# Http Range request Streaming video from url into exoplayer

Tags: performance, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I tried a lot to find the solution to my problem. but I can't make it correct. I want to show and download video from URL. Url will be like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bebMb.jpg

As far my research API in python language and it used partial content with range request in the header. I don't know how to use that API and load video into video view/exoplayer.I tried below way and I got this issue.

"  com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 500"

Anyone pls give me a way to use that api to show and download video

```
     mPlayerView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    mPlayerView.requestFocus();
    TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
            new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
    trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);
    mPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
    player.setPlayWhenReady(shouldAutoPlay);
    MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(mediaDataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(videoPath));
    boolean haveStartPosition = currentWindow != C.INDEX_UNSET;
    if (haveStartPosition) {
        player.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition);
    }
    player.prepare(mediaSource, !haveStartPosition, false);

    player.addListener(new ExoPlayer.EventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest, int reason) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
            if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {

        }


        @Override
        public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekProcessed() {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Response code: 500 error on the server side.

Comment: @Raghunandan because i didnt add range in header.I dont know the way to do

Comment: i don't have much experience in exoplayer. i can't help further. wait till some one answers

Comment: not only in exoplayer.i am asking generally how to show this streams in video player.it may be any

Comment: hey @LavanyaVelusamy I'm having the same issue? any fix?